# How to convert xor, and, not operators mutually

Tags: c, xor

I am reading a paper about cryptographic hash function. It shows a formula conversion that is hard for me to understand.

```
Ch(x,y,z) = (x & y) ^ (~x & z)
```

On the above, `&` is  bitwise-and, `^` is bitwise-xor, `~` is bitwise-not. It can be simplified as following:

```
Ch(x,y,z) = ((y^z)&x)^z
```

I don't know how it is calculated.

Comment: Are you asking how the simplification is carried out?

Comment: You probably need to review some rules of the Boolean Algebra. [take a look](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html)

Comment: It is hard to see intuitively, but a truth table should convince you it is correct.

Comment: yeah, I want to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working backwards, starting with:

```
((y ^ z) & x) ^ z
```

Distribute the "& x":

```
((y & x) ^ (z & x)) ^ z
```

Remove extraneous parentheses:

```
(y & x) ^ (z & x) ^ z
```

Commute operands:

```
(x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ z
```

Add parentheses:

```
(x & y) ^ ((x & z) ^ z)
```

Apply "A ^ B = (~A & B) | (A & ~B)" to right-hand side:

```
(x & y) ^ ((~(x & z) & z) | ((x & z) & ~z))
```

Remove extraneous parentheses:

```
(x & y) ^ ((~(x & z) & z) | (x & z & ~z))
```

Apply "A & ~A = 0":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~(x & z) & z) | (x & 0))
```

Apply "A & 0 = 0":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~(x & z) & z) | (0))
```

Apply "A | 0 = A":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~(x & z) & z))
```

Remove extraneous parentheses:

```
(x & y) ^ (~(x & z) & z)
```

Apply De Morgan's Law "~(A & B) = (~A | ~B)":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~x | ~z) & z)
```

Distribute the "& z":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~x & z) | (~z & z))
```

Apply "A & ~A = 0":

```
(x & y) ^ ((~x & z) | (0))
```

Apply "A | 0 = A":

```
(x & y) ^ (~x & z)
```

Therefore, `(x & y) ^ (~x & z)` is equivalent to `((y ^ z) & x) ^ z`.

Answer (score 2):

> a truth table should convince you it is correct

It's super-tedious to try and draw truth tables in ASCII art, so for the following...

```
z=0      x      z=1      x 
     |  0 1          |  0 1
   --+-------      --+-------      ===     a b   e f
 y 0 |  a b      y 0 |  e f                c d   g h
   1 |  c d        1 |  g h
```

So...

```
x & y  =  0 0   0 0     ~x & z  =  0 0   1 0 
          0 1   0 1                0 0   1 0
```

Therefore:

```
(x&y) ^ (~x&z)  =  0 0   1 0
                   0 1   1 1
```

Now working though the solution in parts:

```
        y ^ z  =  0 0   1 1
                  1 1   0 0

    (y^z) & x  =  0 0   0 1
                  0 1   0 0

((y^z)&x) ^ z  =  0 0   1 0
                  0 1   1 1
```

Which is happily the same as we had for the original expression.